# Can R convert GPX files to KML files?

Tags: r, kml, gpx

There seems to be no relevant content for converting GPX to KML files. R's `sf` package can do it, if you don't care about time and elevation (I do, and that is standard in most KMLs). Does anyone know how to do this in R without downloading any other programs (like GPSbabel)?

Here's a very simple example file. The metadata section is filled with link I don't totally understand, but if I leave them out, they seem to have trouble working with certain software. Could I write something myself? Yes, but I've found that there is enough variability in how gpx files present themselves that I would like to use a package that has been formally developed for this express purpose.

Update: I'm attempting to do this for a track rather than track points, which is why I used a track example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" xmlns:gpxtrkx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackStatsExtension/v1" xmlns:wptx1="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" creator="eTrex 20x" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackStatsExtension/v1 http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackStatsExtension.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1 http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtensionv1.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <link href="http://www.garmin.com">
      <text>Garmin International</text>
    </link>
    <time>2009-10-17T22:58:43Z</time>
  </metadata>
  <trk>
    <name>Example GPX Document</name>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
        <ele>4.46</ele>
        <time>2009-10-17T18:37:26Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
        <ele>4.94</ele>
        <time>2009-10-17T18:37:31Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
        <ele>6.87</ele>
        <time>2009-10-17T18:37:34Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

Comment: It won't help with R, but you can easily convert from GPX to KML using Google Earth Pro.

Comment: Can you share an example file?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following might work. Please note that the last step (i.e. reading `KML` file) might be quite tricky on Windows/macOS:

1: Load `sf` package

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.7.1, GDAL 2.4.2, PROJ 5.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
```

2: Load and write toy `GPX` data

```r
gpx_data <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" xmlns:gpxtrkx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackStatsExtension/v1" xmlns:wptx1="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" creator="eTrex 20x" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackStatsExtension/v1 http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackStatsExtension.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1 http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtensionv1.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <link href="http://www.garmin.com">
      <text>Garmin International</text>
    </link>
    <time>2009-10-17T22:58:43Z</time>
  </metadata>
  <trk>
    <name>Example GPX Document</name>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
        <ele>4.46</ele>
        <time>2009-10-17T18:37:26Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
        <ele>4.94</ele>
        <time>2009-10-17T18:37:31Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
        <ele>6.87</ele>
        <time>2009-10-17T18:37:34Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
'
gpx_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".gpx")
writeLines(gpx_data, gpx_file)
```

3: Read-in the `gpx` data

```r
gpx <- st_read(gpx_file, "track_points")
#> Reading layer `track_points' from data source 
#>   `/tmp/RtmpJJwAhb/file77d3752cf80.gpx' using driver `GPX'
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 26 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -122.3269 ymin: 47.64455 xmax: -122.3269 ymax: 47.64455
#> CRS:           4326
gpx
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 26 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -122.3269 ymin: 47.64455 xmax: -122.3269 ymax: 47.64455
#> CRS:           4326
#>   track_fid track_seg_id track_seg_point_id  ele                time magvar
#> 1         0            0                  0 4.46 2009-10-17 20:37:26     NA
#> 2         0            0                  1 4.94 2009-10-17 20:37:31     NA
#> 3         0            0                  2 6.87 2009-10-17 20:37:34     NA
#>   geoidheight name  cmt desc  src link1_href link1_text link1_type link2_href
#> 1          NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
#> 2          NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
#> 3          NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
#>   link2_text link2_type  sym type  fix sat hdop vdop pdop ageofdgpsdata dgpsid
#> 1       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA   NA   NA   NA            NA     NA
#> 2       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA   NA   NA   NA            NA     NA
#> 3       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA   NA   NA   NA            NA     NA
#>                     geometry
#> 1 POINT (-122.3269 47.64455)
#> 2 POINT (-122.3269 47.64455)
#> 3 POINT (-122.3269 47.64455)
```

4: Convert to `KML` format. If you omit the option `-fieldTypeToString` `DateTime`(which converts `DateTime` class into `Strings`), GDAL raises a warning saying that `KML` format does not support DateTime fields.

```r
kml_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".kml")
gdal_utils(
  util = "vectortranslate", 
  source = gpx_file, 
  destination = kml_file, 
  options = c("-f", "KML", "-fieldTypeToString", "DateTime", "track_points"), 
  quiet = FALSE
)
```

5: Read-in the KML file.

```r
kml <- st_read(kml_file)
#> Reading layer `track_points' from data source 
#>   `/tmp/RtmpJJwAhb/file77d33bffefef.kml' using driver `LIBKML'
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 36 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -122.3269 ymin: 47.64455 xmax: -122.3269 ymax: 47.64455
#> CRS:           4326
kml
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 36 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -122.3269 ymin: 47.64455 xmax: -122.3269 ymax: 47.64455
#> CRS:           4326
#>   Name description timestamp begin  end altitudeMode tessellate extrude
#> 1 <NA>        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>         <NA>         -1       0
#> 2 <NA>        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>         <NA>         -1       0
#> 3 <NA>        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>         <NA>         -1       0
#>   visibility drawOrder icon track_fid track_seg_id track_seg_point_id  ele
#> 1         -1        NA <NA>         0            0                  0 4.46
#> 2         -1        NA <NA>         0            0                  1 4.94
#> 3         -1        NA <NA>         0            0                  2 6.87
#>                     time magvar geoidheight  cmt desc  src link1_href
#> 1 2009/10/17 18:37:26+00     NA          NA <NA> <NA> <NA>       <NA>
#> 2 2009/10/17 18:37:31+00     NA          NA <NA> <NA> <NA>       <NA>
#> 3 2009/10/17 18:37:34+00     NA          NA <NA> <NA> <NA>       <NA>
#>   link1_text link1_type link2_href link2_text link2_type  sym type  fix sat
#> 1       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA
#> 2       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA
#> 3       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA
#>   hdop vdop pdop ageofdgpsdata dgpsid                   geometry
#> 1   NA   NA   NA            NA     NA POINT (-122.3269 47.64455)
#> 2   NA   NA   NA            NA     NA POINT (-122.3269 47.64455)
#> 3   NA   NA   NA            NA     NA POINT (-122.3269 47.64455)
```

Please note that you need the LIBKML driver to properly read the KML file. See also https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/499

```r
st_drivers()[with(st_drivers(), grep("KML", name)), ] 
#>          name                        long_name write  copy is_raster is_vector
#> LIBKML LIBKML Keyhole Markup Language (LIBKML)  TRUE FALSE     FALSE      TRUE
#> KML       KML    Keyhole Markup Language (KML)  TRUE FALSE     FALSE      TRUE
#>         vsi
#> LIBKML TRUE
#> KML    TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
#>  os       Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language en_GB:en
#>  collate  en_GB.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_GB.UTF-8
#>  tz       Europe/Rome
#>  date     2022-03-24
#>  pandoc   2.17.1.1 @ /home/ag21052/.local/bin/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  sf          * 1.0-5   2021-12-17 [3] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#> 
#>  [1] /home/ag21052/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6
#>  [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#>  [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#>  [4] /usr/lib/R/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Thanks for this post. I am attempting to make the conversion for a track as opposed to points, which is why I used a track as my example. Sorry for the confusion, I should have been more specific in the post.

Comment: Ah, I see that I can change `track_points` to `tracks`, and it makes a track. But it still drops the time.

Comment: Hi. I'm not an expert on GPX format, but maybe there is a problem with the input data? Because when I run `st_read(gpx_file, "tracks")` I can see that the `ele` and `time` are not imported (maybe because there are linked to the single points and not the complete track?)

Comment: I ran it on real gpx files from a Garmin device and got the same result. Just like `st_write`, `gdal_utils` seems to drop the time in any case.